# How can I make all my processes start with niceness 5

Tags: users, settings, nice

I know that niceness values are inherited from the niceness value of the parent process, but can I globally change the default niceness value for a particular user (myself).

In this case I have a small convenience server in mind, which is exclusively accessed via `ssh`. So, I think I could change my default shell from `/bin/bash` to `/etc/bash5` while `/etc/bash5` is this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
nice -n 5 /bin/bash

#file privileges: root:root 755
```

This strikes me as a terrible hack and error prone. There must be a better way.

I'm mostly interested in general solutions, that would also apply to a desktop/laptop system.

---

### Edit: I tried the suggested `limits.conf` change, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
root@server# addgroup nice
root@server# adduser myself nice
root@server# echo '@nice soft nice 5' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Then, from my client machine, I say

```
myself@client$ ssh server
myself@server$ sleep 1h &
myself@server$ htop
```

Now, the `sleep` process has an **initial niceness value of `0`**, but if I change the value with `F8` to 19 and then try to reduce it again with `F7` **it stops at `5`**.

### Edit2: Solution

Instead of using the `nice` item in `limits.conf`, you actually have to use `priority` although it is counter-intuitive.

```
@nice soft priority 5
```

Comment: Maybe put a `renice -n 5` in your `~/.profile`?

Comment: @jw013: That's a better idea than my `bash5` approach, I give you this. But it still breaks if I say `ssh myserver -- somecommand` doesn't it?

Comment: @bitmask. I cannot reproduce your result for `limits.conf`. What's your output for `ps -o pid,nice,cmd`?

Comment: Please post solutions to your own problems as _answers_, rather than edits to your question. Thanks! (It's okay to provide your own answer to your own question.)

Comment: On another note: this isn't what you asked, but you may find that cgroups provide more effective way of doing what (reduced priority for a certain user) you want than `nice`.

Comment: @mattdm: I just wanted to sum up the accepted answer, because I previously stated incorrectly that it didn't work.

Comment: The checkbox signifies that you think it works. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the priority for a particular user in `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

```
root       hard/soft     priority    10
```

This way u can set hard or soft limit for any particular user. So all the processes which this root user will start will have 5 as the default priority vale.

According to [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29):

> The exact mathematical effect of setting a particular niceness value
>   for a process depends on the details of how the scheduler is designed
>   on that implementation of Unix.

Here is the snapshot which show the above procedure works:

[image: This image is the screenshot of /etc/security/limits.conf file]

This is snapshot of `limits.conf` file which show a line which i added at last like

```
root     hard     priority    15
```

After changing this, I started one ssh session using the command `ssh root@localhost`

[image]

This screenshot show last two lines which shows the nice value of last two processes `-bash` and `sshd: root@pts/3` to be 15.

**Edit**

Here is the snapshot which shows that u can increase and decrease the niceness of a process
[image]

**Edit 2:**

Here is the snapshort which shows that even normal user can change the niceness value.

[image]

Comment: I was talking about **niceness**, not priority. And as I said on the other answer, it doesn't seem to be accepted. Do I have to restart some daemon, or something?

Comment: @bitmask: this one is working in mine...I am going to add snapshot in my answer wait...

Comment: @bitmask: I have updated the answer with the snapshots..:)

Comment: There is a difference between **niceness** and **priority**. I totally buy that you can change the *hard priority*, but I want to change the *soft niceness*. That's a different thing.

Comment: @bitmask: Accirind to wiki page, `A niceness of −20 is the highest priority and 19 or 20 is the lowest priority`. So first u have to understand that niceness and priority are same..And I want to clear that these are `hard and soft limits` but its not like `hard priority` and `soft niceness`..

Comment: @bitmask: The thing is higher the niceness value,lower is its priority and vice-versa..thats all..

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the `limits.conf` man page. I understood the `priority` setting would directly affect the actual priority of the process. But it doesn't, it still sets the niceness. Thus, my stubbornness.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri it seems that only root can decrease niceness.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: its not like this..every user can increase or decrease the nice value of the processes owned by it..You can see this thing by first giving `htop` command and then increase/decrease the nice value owned by that user by pressing F8/F7...

Comment: @pradeepchhetri, I cant decrease the nice value, the man page of `htop` 0.8.3 on Debian Squeeze states that only superuser can do that. `renice` also gives me a "permission denied" error.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: I am able to do it in Ubuntu 12.04...wait i will attach the screenshot for you in the above answer.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: i have attached the snapshot :P

Comment: @pradeepchhetri: I can *increase* the nice value as a non-root user. I can't *decrease* the nice value.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: i am sorry, ya exactly u can't decrease the nice value.

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-niceprocesses.html)  you can set a default priority for a user in `limits.conf`, with a line like:

```
username    soft  priority  5
```

See man [limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf).

Comment: Sounds great. I just gave it a shot (using a special group though) `@nice  soft nice 5` but `ssh`ing into the machine and executing `sleep 1h` shows as having niceness `0` in `htop`. Any clue why the setting wasn't accepted? I'm on debian squeeze.

Comment: what is `@nice` in the above comment..it should be the one of the user of ur linux machine.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri: See the edit of my OP, please. It's a group name.

Comment: why @ in front of group name while putting an entry in `limits.conf` file ?

Comment: @pradeepchhetri: Because the man page says so?

Comment: @bitmask: use hard inspite of soft..it will work ..

Comment: @pradeepchhetri: Yes, but will not allow me to `renice` something to `0`. I just want the **initial** niceness to be `5`, but I should be able to adjust the niceness manually to something between `0` and `19`.

Comment: @bitmask: No, Its not at all like this..You can increase and decrease the nice value even after that.. I can show u that also in my answer snapshots..

Comment: @pradeepchhetri: Yes, because you're changing the *priority*, which has little to do with the niceness. **I do not want to change the priority.**

Comment: @bitmask, I haven't tried this myself, but from the first link: "`@lusers hard priority 5` is the same as running... `nice -n 5` on all processes that the user runs". My googlings indicate that *niceness* and *priority* are near synonyms. What definition are you working from? `nice` in limits.conf sets the maximum priority not the default.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: I was thinking about the priority that the kernel generates based on the niceness, but that's not as independent from the niceness as I thought.

Comment: Fair enough @bitmask. I'll just be down here feeling the butthurt 'cos pradeepchhetri got the accepted answer. :(

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: I'm sorry. You are technically correct: your answer was first. But he managed to convince me that my mental model was wrong. However, I can at least fix the missing +1.

Comment: @bitmask shouldn't you re-edit your question to up date your findings?

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: Fair enough. Updated.